ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED when file-type used in nest.js
I'm using file-type in nest.js and I've this error, using the last 19.4.1 version.
nest start
node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:597
      throw e;
      ^

Error [ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED]: No "exports" main defined in D:\dev\olhos\nest-test\node_modules\file-type\package.json
    at exportsNotFound (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:304:10)
    at packageExportsResolve (node:internal/modules/esm/resolve:594:13)
    at resolveExports (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:590:36)
    at Module._findPath (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:667:31)
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1129:27)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:984:27)
    at Module.require (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1231:19)
    at require (node:internal/modules/helpers:179:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (D:\dev\olhos\nest-test\src\app.controller.ts:3:1)
    at Module._compile (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1369:14) {
  code: 'ERR_PACKAGE_PATH_NOT_EXPORTED'
}

To simply reproduce the problem:
npm i -g @nestjs/cli
nest new nest-test
cd nest-test
npm i file-type

Edit the sample controller, scaffolded from nest.js:
import { Controller, Get } from '@nestjs/common';
import { AppService } from './app.service';
import { fileTypeFromFile } from 'file-type';

@Controller()
export class AppController {
  constructor(private readonly appService: AppService) {}

  @Get()
  async getHello(): Promise<string> {
    return (await fileTypeFromFile('Unicorn.png')).mime;
  }
}

nest start

Any idea?
Thanks
Nest.js starts as expected

This is more than likely an error that is arising from file-type being an ESM package and not a CJS compatible one. Not really much you can do other than use an async import() function to resolve it and use it that way instead

I've tried in this way but it doesn't work, also with await import used directly in async funcion, the same exception is raised.
